# Is it possible to compile unittest without running them and explicitly run unittest for a specific module?

Tags: d

I often wrote my test code in the main function while developing an API but because D has integrated unittest I want to start using them.

My current work flow is the following, I have a script that watches for file changes in any .d files, if the scripts finds a modified file it will run `dub build`

The problem is that `dub build` doesn't seem to build the unittest

```
module foo

struct Bar{..}

unittest{
...
// some syntax error here
...
}
```

It only compiles the unittests if I explicitly run `dub test`. But I don't want to run and compile them at the same time.

The second problem is that I want to be able to run unittests for a single module for example

`dub test module foo`

Would this be possible?

Comment: phobos itself has a [Makefile rule](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/posix.mak#L350) to test a single module, but I haven't dug far enough into how it works to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can program a custom test runner using the trait [getUnittests](http://dlang.org/spec/traits.html#getUnitTests).

> getUnitTests
>
> Takes one argument, a symbol of an aggregate (e.g. struct/class/module). The result is a tuple of all the unit test functions of that aggregate. The functions returned are like normal nested static functions, CTFE will work and UDA's will be accessible.

in your `main()` you should be able to write something that takes an arbitrary number of module:

```
void runModuleTests(Modules...)()
{
    static if (Modules.length > 1)
        runModuleTests!(Modules[1..$]);
    else static if (Modules.length == 1)
        foreach(test; __traits(getUnitTests, Modules[0])) test;
}
```

of course the switch `-unittest` must be passed to dmd