# Unit testing D library

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, d

The built-in unit testing functionality (`unittest {...}` code blocks) seems to only be activated when running.

How can I activate unit tests in a library with no `main` function?

This is somewhat related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35075253/2658159), although the accepted answer there deals with a workaround via the `main` function.

As an example, I would expect unit testing to fail on a file containing only this code:

```
int foo(int i) { return i + 1; }

unittest {
  assert(foo(1) == 1); // should fail
}
```

You'll notice I don't have `module` declared at the top. I'm not sure if that matters for this specific question, but in reality I would have a `module` statement at the top.

Comment: https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/gems/unittesting ?

Comment: try `dmd -main -unittest yourfile.d`

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe unfortunately running that gives no indication that unit tests are failing. let me know if i need to give a code example.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe question edited to provide simple code example, which does not work with suggestion

Comment: that just compiles the program, you still need to run it afterward

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe ah! okay, ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I activate unit tests in a library with no main function?

You can use DMD's `-main` switch, or rdmd's `--main` switch, to add an empty `main` function to the set of compiled source files. This allows creating a unit test binary for your library.

If you use Dub, `dub test` will do something like the above automatically.

Comment: question edited to provide simple code example, which does not work with this.

Comment: Don't forget to compile with `-unittest` as well as `-main`! `dmd -main -unittest -run test.d` correctly shows a unittest failure for me.

Comment: Thank you, yes I was forgetting the `-run` part